# What does the abbrevation “o.E.” stand for?

Tags: abbreviation, mathematics

Reading a mathematical paper written in German, I can’t understand the following abbrevation:

> o.E. f(x) := 0 für x ∈ M, sonst löse …

(proof of theorem 2.4.5 in [this diploma thesis](http://www.math.kit.edu/iana1/~lamm/media/dipl.pdf); page 57)

It should be something like “let f(x) = 0 for x ∈ M, and consider the following …”.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This stands for *ohne Einschränkung*, short for *[ohne Beschränkung der Allgemeinheit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohne_Beschr%C3%A4nkung_der_Allgemeinheit)* and would *usually* be abbreviated as “o.B.d.A.” The english equivalent is “[WLOG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality)”, which is short for *without loss of generality* and carries the exact same meaning: the assumption holds for all cases, not just the discussed special case.

Answer (score 5):

Is this a mathematical formula or a part of a mathematical proof?

If it is a proof then it seems:
o.E. ohne Einschränkung (without limitation/exception) but as a mathematician i should say i only know the abbreviation "o.B.d.A. ohne Beschränkung der Allgemeinheit" which more or less means the same!

See also [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/OE)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should guess that mean, WLOG, is so commonly used in english.

Comment: In fact, it is the first sentence of the *proof*.

Comment: Great i found the Wikipedia explanation but it didn't suit me so i added oBdA=WLOG